# Create and parse json using Gson with nested object with local date

Tags: android, json, gson

I have this error, when try parse my json

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was NAME at line 1 column 313 path $.reminder
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was NAME at line 1 column 313 path $.reminder
    at app//com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:395)
    at app//com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:1214)
    at app//com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:1124)
    at app//com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:1034)
    at app//com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:969)
    at app//com.mitchell.android.core.extensions.StringKt.fromJson(String.kt:23)
    at app//com.mitchell.android.TaskTest.json(TaskTest.kt:26)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was NAME at line 1 column 313 path $.reminder
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextString(JsonReader.java:834)
    at com.mitchell.android.core.extensions.ReminderAdapter.read(Gson.kt:67)
    at com.mitchell.android.core.extensions.ReminderAdapter.read(Gson.kt:59)
```

I have object Task and it has nested object Remind which contains LocalDate and it carsh my fromJson method, what I should to do?

toJson return this string

```
{"id":"958736db-d680-47d7-af68-488d3fde6a20","categoryId":"none","title":"","reminder":"{\"reminderId\":\"d59012da-6eeb-470a-9268-79e5df337ef0\",\"frequency\":\"EVERY_DAY\",\"remind\":{\"id\":\"37296d21-c266-4497-9be6-831f7fb8ff56\",\"hour\":0,\"minute\":49},\"startDate\":\"2023-01-03\",\"endDate\":\"null\"}","completed":false,"createdAt":"2023-01-03T00:49:55.980456600"}
```

```
fun Any.toJson(): String? {
    val builder = GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(LocalDate::class.java, LocalDateAdapter())
        .registerTypeAdapter(LocalDateTime::class.java, LocalDateTimeAdapter())
    if (this !is Reminder) {
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(Reminder::class.java, ReminderAdapter())
    }
    return builder.create().toJson(this)
}

class LocalDateAdapter : TypeAdapter<LocalDate?>() {
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun read(jsonReader: JsonReader): LocalDate? {
        println("LocalDateAdapter: ${jsonReader.nextString()}")
        return try {
            if (jsonReader.nextString() != null && jsonReader.hasNext()) LocalDate.parse(jsonReader.nextString()) else null
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            null
        }
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun write(out: JsonWriter?, value: LocalDate?) {
        println("LocalDateAdapter w: $value")

        out?.value(value.toString())
    }

}
```

This is method creash my app when I try create POJO from string

```
fun <T> String?.fromJson(clazz: Class<T>): T? {
    val builder = GsonBuilder()


    if (clazz != Reminder::class.java) {
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(LocalDate::class.java, LocalDateAdapter())
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(LocalDateTime::class.java, LocalDateTimeAdapter())
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(Reminder::class.java, ReminderAdapter())
    }

    return builder.create().fromJson(this, clazz)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code of your custom `TypeAdapter` implementations, in particular their `read` methods. They must either:

- consume a single JSON value
  (a complete JSON array or object and all its nested values also counts as one value)
- or, thrown an exception

If they do not adhere to this, JSON parsing will fail (possibly in cryptic ways).

Your `LocalDateAdapter` already violates this:

- It tries to call `nextString()` up to 3 times while it should call it exactly once
  (all `next...` methods of `JsonReader` consume the next value)
- It calls `hasNext()`
  This is redundant because `TypeAdapter.read` is normally only called when it is known that there is a next element. `hasNext()` is only needed when you use `beginArray()` or `beginObject()` and then manually parse a JSON array or object.
- It simply returns `null` when an exception occurs without knowing exactly which function call threw the exception

I would recommend to just implement the `read` method like this:

```kotlin
override fun read(jsonReader: JsonReader): LocalDate {
    return LocalDate.parse(jsonReader.nextString())
}
```

If you really need exception handling for malformed dates, then only put the `try` around the `LocalDate.parse` call and call `nextString()` outside of it.